# How to containerize this application, using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am developing a component (data pipeline) for a larger distributed system which forms the backend infrastructure of an application.

I want to containerize the sub components of this component (the pipeline), so that (if need be), each sub component or "service/container" (in Docker lingo), can be run on a separate physical machine.

However, some of the sub components are themselves composed of other services. I am new to Docker and docker-compose, and would appreciate some help in putting together a docker-compose file(s) to create/configure the system.

Here is my dev tree structure, whioch largely follows the partitioning between the proposed services/containers:

```
├── db
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── ETL
│   ├── archivers
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── feeds
│       ├── feeds
│       └── scrapy.cfg
├── mdal
│   ├── data
│   │   └── data_file
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── MANIFEST.in
│   ├── README.rst
│   ├── sample
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── package_data.dat
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_simple.py
│   └── tox.ini
├── README
└── restapi
    └── Dockerfile
```

The definitions of the various servces/components/containers are laid out below:

```
Service          Description
========         ===================================================
db               postgresql service, mounted on persistant volume
ETL              ETL service (uses mdal to load/write from/to db)
mdal             Python dbal package used by some components (uses db service)
restapi          Nginx + gunicorn + flask app (uses mdal)
```

Here is my attempt at the topmost docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    # PostgreSQL service:
    db:
      container_name: postgres
      restart: always      
      image: postgres:9.6.1
      ports:
        # We'll bind our host's port 5432 to postgres's port 5432, so we can use
        # our database IDEs with it:
        - 5432:5432

      environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PG_PASS        


    # ETL service
    ETL:
      container_name: ETL
      # Should install mdal package when being built
      # Should link to my source files so changes are reflected


    # Nginx + Gunicorn + Flask app exposing REST API
    restapi:
      container_name: restapi
      # Should pull (versioned) Docker image for Nginx, Gunicorn, Flask
      # Should link to my flask source files so changes are reflected
      # Should install mdal package when being built
```

How would I write the `docker-copose.yml` file to obtain the desired functionality as stated above?

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right way with the base structure, but this a quite complex configuration if you are new to Docker and it's concepts. I'll try to explain how to configure each service step by step.

### Defaults

- your services will be available on the docker-compose network with the same names you're using. So the `db` service will be the `db` host inside the network
- all docker-compose services can communicate, so you can reach the `db` host from the `ETL` host. If you want, you can create service names alias using [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) (be careful: links is a legacy feature and may be removed)

### Postgres

The db needs only to be attached to a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) to persist data as you want:

```
db:
  image: postgres:9.6.1
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
  ports:
    # to attach external GUIs
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PG_PASS
```

- `./pg-data` is a local directory (relative to your docker-compose file) on your host OS (it will be created if not exists).
- `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is the default postgres default directory.
- your local directory `./pg-data` will be mapped to the container `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, so postgres will write inside it.

I see a `Dockerfile` inside your `db` directory: if you use [the official postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) you don't need it.

### ETL

To build services located in subdirectories you can use a custom [build context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context). I will build you service image from the specified directory, using the relative `Dockerfile`. You can customize the build further, using the [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile) option.

To link your sources to the container just use another volume:

```
ETL:
  build:
    context: ./ETL
  volumes:
    - ./ETL:/YOUR/CONTAINER/APP_DIR
```

This requires that your service `Dockerfile` should be like this:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "python", "my-app.py"]
```

In this case, the docker-compose volume for the ETL service will be:

```
  volumes:
    - ./ETL:/usr/src/app
```

**QUESTIONS**:
- `Should install mdal package when being built`: what does it mean? where and how it can be installed?

### restapi

Nginx will be the reverse proxy of your gunicorn/flask app. So you need two services:

- a nginx service configured as a reverse proxy
- a service that runs your gunicorn/flask app (the `restapi` service)

### Nginx

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volume:
    - ./restapi/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Nginx will be the main access point for your app, so the port 80 is exposed on you host: you can reach your app at `http://localhost`.

The volume is a "trick" to add a configuration file to the official nginx image without creating a custom one. By default nginx will load any `.conf` file available inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d`. We're overwriting the container [`default.conf`](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/1d2e2ccae2f6e478f628f4091d8a5c36a122a157/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile#L137) at runtime with our custom configuration file.

This is an example configuration file, you should save it as `./restapi/nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  ~^.*$;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://restapi:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

### The gunicorn/flask app

Here you should have somewhere a Dockerfile that run you app using something like `gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app` (I've taken the basic example from [the gunicorn website](http://gunicorn.org/#quickstart)).

```
restapi:
  build:
    context: ./restapi
  expose:
    - "8000"
```

We're exposing the gunicorn port to the docker network (you can't reach it directly from you host, but nginx can).

### mdal

Who is using this? Where is it required?

### A suggested reading list

While the [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#docker-architecture) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) docs are very detailed, I suggest you some books that explain the (too) many docker features (and quirks):

- [Docker in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/docker-in-action-second-edition): Dockerfiles, images, registries, networks, volumes. Everything you need to know. A must read from my point of view.
- [Docker in Practice](https://www.manning.com/books/docker-in-practice-second-edition): many interesting and useful (even extreme) use cases and solutions. A cookbook.
- [The Docker book](https://www.dockerbook.com/): learn by practical examples.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response (I upvoted your answer for the sheer quantity of detail). I will be following the steps you outlined this evening and if all works out well, I'll accept it as the answer. It is times like this (and with people like you), that make Stackoverflow a truly helpful and useful resource. Once again, thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help you with this. Ask more if you don't solve it.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about your answer. I'm still battling with some issues (and don't want to pester you with questions - until I'm absoluely run out of ideas/am stuck). Once I get my basic understanding of all of the moving parts intact, I will review your answer, extract general ideas from it and apply to my specific situation before marking this as the final answer. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: + for books list